# Meaning of "ascended on the high and taken it"? (Psalm 68:18)

Tags: midrash

What are the various meanings or references of this phrase, particularly the meaning of "ascended on high and taken it", the parenthesis shows that Torah is the object of achieving, but there maybe more references to the same on this description of the highest achievement. Is Torah obedience is considered the highest achievement, implying that it is a very difficult endeavour, or is it prophetically interpreted?

Sifrei Devarim [49:2](https://www.sefaria.org/Sifrei_Devarim.49.2)

> "and to cleave to Him": How is it possible for a man to ascend the heights and cleave to Him? Is it not written (Ibid. 4:24) "For the L-rd your G-d is a consuming fire"? and (Daniel 8:9) "His throne was like a fiery flame and its wheels like burning fire"? But, (the intent is) cleave to the sages and to the disciples, and I will account it to you as if **you had ascended the heights and had taken it (the Torah)**. And not as if you had taken it peacefully, but as if you had waged war and taken it. And thus is it written (Psalms 68:19) "You ascended on high; you took spoils; you took gifts for man."

Comment: תפלה למשה איש האל'

Comment: "Ascended on high", according to Rashi means that Moshe Rabbeinu ascended to the Heavens when G-d gave us the Torah. "implying that it is a very difficult endeavour" - Certainly no, the Torah attest to that saying that Torah Lo Bashamayim Hi. - The Torah is not in the Heaven, it is up to reach for us.